# Path/File Access error Runtime 75 - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is the continuation of a previous issue that I was helped with. I have attempted to combine 2 sub routines so that the text files which are created have the white spaces removed at the end. Looking at the code below I get a path file error on the line -
     Open inFile For Input As #1

Having debugged I can see that the file name stored in strFile disappears when the second routine is called. Can anyone see where my error is why it is doing this and help me fix it please? AltText_V2 is the second routine. I have updated the code to just include the part where the issue is

```
 Option Explicit

  Public Sub AltText_V2()
  Dim inFile As String
  Dim outFile As String
  Dim data As String
  Dim strFile As String

  'Ensures that the file open directory is always the same
  ChDir "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\"

 'inFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
  inFile = strFile
  Open inFile For Input As #1

  outFile = inFile & ".txt"
  Open outFile For Output As #2

  Do Until EOF(1)
  Line Input #1, data

  If Trim(data) <> "" Then
     Print #2, data
  End If
  Loop

  Close #1
  Close #2

  Kill inFile
  Name outFile As inFile

  MsgBox "File alteration completed!"
  End Sub
```

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - and consider reducing the amount of code in your question to just the issue you are dealing with.

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie, I have updated the code, I hope it is within the guidelines a little better now

Comment: That's a lot more readable - I note you haven't assigned a value to `strFile` - are you missing something like `strFile = "YourFile.foo"` ?

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie The value is of strFile is picked up in the first sub routine as part of the Save As for the initial text file that is created but when it is picked up in the second routine it disappears...

Comment: Maybe you want to be passing the `strFile` variable to `AltText_V2` i.e. `Sub AltText_V2(strFile As String)` and then get rid of the `Dim strFile As String` declaration.

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie that makes sense, although do I need to change the call name as I get a compile error on the call when I try and execute this now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually worked it out. I simply declared the variable outside of the sub routine and it worked a treat so it looked like this.

```
 Option Explicit
 Dim strFile As String

 Public Sub OneRoutine()
```